# Error connecting to Redis on .net Core app hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, caching, redis, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

We have a redis cache hosted on Azure and we use the following as a service in our .net core application:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(provider => 
    ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection"))
);
```

Our connection string is similar to the following:

```
ourserver.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=******=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,syncTimeout=4000
```

in getting from cache we don't face problems but if we add to cache we sometimes get the following error:

> "StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to
>   connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer,
>   disable AbortOnConnectFail. ConnectTimeout"

I have read solutions like setting `abortconnect` to `false` and increasing the timeout but I have implemented it like the connection string above.

If you have suggestions or you think that we have a problem with the connection string kindly advise.

Update: we have implemented a solution to solve connectivity issue but now we get this:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your connectTimeout set to? Can you try increasing that to see if it helps?

Comment: Please see connection string above. The timeout is 4000

Comment: 4000 is your syncTimout (that's your operation Timeout). There is another property called "connectTimeout" which is the timeout specially for connecting. If you haven't changed it, it should be 5000 (the default value)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the recommended  connecttimeout please?

Comment: The default of 5000 should be sufficient unless you are going cross region and you might need to increase it.

I see you mention >>>> "In getting from cache we don't face problems but if we add to cache we sometimes get the following error".

This is interesting as why only a SET would fail, but not a GET. Could you perhaps be recreating a connection each time when doing a SET? Can you show how you are setting up and then using the ConnectionMultiplexer? It could potentially also be a stability issue with the Nuget package in the NET Core binaries. What NuGet package version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it appears that it happens even in get... after implementing isconnected() first, I now get this error: No connection is available to service this operation

Comment: I have explained in more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297125/error-in-redis-connection-in-asp-net-core-app-hosted-on-azure

Comment: Thanks. I have put in some comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297125/error-in-redis-connection-in-asp-net-core-app-hosted-on-azure.