# Error in Redis Connection in ASP.NET Core App Hosted on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, caching, redis, asp.net-core

We are facing problems with Redis caching and it's causing crashes in our site.

The following is how we implemented it:

We used the following connection string:

```
"*******.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=*****=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"
```

We created a service class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SarahahDataAccessLayer;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;

namespace Sarahah.Services
{
    public class RedisService
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;
        private readonly ApplicationSettings _settings;
        public RedisService(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
            lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_settings.RedisConnection);
            });
        }



        public  ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs I use the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<RedisService>();
```

Then in controllers we use dependency injection and we assign to a multiplexer:

```
connectionMultiplexer = redisService.Connection;
```

This is how we get from the cache:

```
 private async Task<string> GetFromCache(string key)
    {
        if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
        {
            var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

                return await cache.StringGetAsync(key);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is how we delete:

```
  private async Task DeleteFromCache(string subdomain)
    {

            if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
            {
                var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
                await cache.KeyDeleteAsync(subdomain).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
    }
```

This is how we add:

```
 {
        if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
        {
            var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

                TimeSpan expiresIn;
                // Search Cache
                if (key.Contains("-"))
                {
                    expiresIn = new TimeSpan(0, GetMessagesCacheExpiryMinutes, 0);
                }
                // User info cache
                else
                {
                    expiresIn = new TimeSpan(GetProfileCacheExpiryHours, 0, 0);
                }
                await cache.StringSetAsync(key, serializedData, expiresIn).ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
```

However, we get the following error:
**No connection is available to service this operation**

Although we have a lot of users, we only see few connections in Azure portal:

[image: Very small number of connections]

Please note that we hosted the redis cache in the same region of the web app.

Your support is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Each time your dependency injection calls instantiates the RedisService class, your code ends up assigning a new `Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>` to lazyConnection, thus resulting in a new connection as well as a connection leak as you are not calling Close() or Dispose() on the old lazyConnection.

Try changing your code like this:

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            .........<whatever you have here>
            services.AddSingleton<RedisService>();
            services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings").Bind(options));
        }
```

RedisService.cs

```
public class RedisService
{
    private readonly ApplicationSettings _settings;
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;
    static object connectLock = new object();

    public RedisService(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
        if (lazyConnection == null)
        {
            lock (connectLock)
            {
                if (lazyConnection == null)
                {
                    lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
                    {
                        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_settings.RedisConnection);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationSettings.cs

```
public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        public string RedisConnection { get; set; }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "ApplicationSettings": {
        "RedisConnection": "yourcachename.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=yourpassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,syncTimeout=4000"
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private RedisService redisService;
        private ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer;
        public HomeController(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
        {
            redisService = new RedisService(settings);
            connectionMultiplexer = RedisService.Connection;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            AddToCache("foo1", "bar").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return View();
        }

        private async Task<string> GetFromCache(string key)
        {
            if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
            {
                var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

                return await cache.StringGetAsync(key);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private async Task DeleteFromCache(string subdomain)
        {
            if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
            {
                var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
                await cache.KeyDeleteAsync(subdomain).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private async Task AddToCache(string key, string serializedData)
        {
            var GetMessagesCacheExpiryMinutes = 5;
            var GetProfileCacheExpiryHours = 1;
            if (connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected)
            {
                var cache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

                TimeSpan expiresIn;
                // Search Cache
                if (key.Contains("-"))
                {
                    expiresIn = new TimeSpan(0, GetMessagesCacheExpiryMinutes, 0);
                }
                // User info cache
                else
                {
                    expiresIn = new TimeSpan(GetProfileCacheExpiryHours, 0, 0);
                }
                await cache.StringSetAsync(key, serializedData, expiresIn).ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. But I notice you mention:
redisService = new RedisService(settings);
What is redisService variable? 
We have modified the implementation to the following:
      new RedisService(settings);
      connectionMultiplexer = RedisService.Connection;
 is this what you meant by any chance?

Comment: I tried to create a new variable (redisService) but then I can't call redisService.connection as I get an error.

Comment: When we used the way I mentioned in the first column the error still shows. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code above to have all the pieces you need. I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I get: Member RedisService.Connection cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead. (on this line:             connectionMultiplexer = redisService.Connection;)

Comment: Connection is a static property. Please access it as RedisService,Connection instead of redisService.Connection. Please see how I have used it in my example above.

Comment: Thanks a million. We have used it without assignment to redisService variable (i.e the line only has new RedisService(settings)) is there a problem with that?

Comment: You can't access static members with instance syntax. So, to access the static Connection property you have to do it like RedisService.Connection without the "new".

Comment: What I meant is rather than redisService = new RedisService(settings) we only have new RedisService(settings). No assignment to a variable. Is that ok?

Comment: That should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately, the error happened again and the site crashed.

Comment: Can you email azurecache@microsoft.com with details listed here https://gist.github.com/JonCole/132b255425268459ec95#file-supportquestionnaire-md?

Comment: We also run into this error, but simply only using IDistributedCache from Microsoft Extensions. In startup.cs            
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o =>
            {
                o.Configuration = RedisCacheConnectionString;
            });

looking at the sources

https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/9bc79b2f25a3724376d7af19617c33749a30ea3a/src/Caching/Redis/src/RedisCache.cs

It also create a new Connect() every time Set method is called

@CarlDacosta ?  Or is IDistributedCache always a Singleton? That Connect checks if there is a _cache assigned.

Comment: Seems like it is a singleton in ASP.NET Core https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/efbbdc5e0a8c8a664ea34cd41220d084b6906f57/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23